# Hibernate validation results in Spring TransactionSystemException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am using Spring 4.3.3, Spring Data 1.10.5, Hibernate 5.0.11 and Hibernate Validator 5.3.1.

The problem is that when validation fails I would expect

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

to be thrown out of my JUnit test, but instead

```
org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:138)
```

throws

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
```

which eventually results in weird

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException
```

How can I fix it?

Code available at [GitHub](https://github.com/nikolayspb/urlshortener/blob/master/src/test/java/com/urlshortener/service/AccountServiceImplFailureTest.java), line 24 and 29.

Full stacktrace is

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:484)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.createAccount(Unknown Source)
at com.urlshortener.service.AccountServiceImplTest.testCreateAccountEmptyName(AccountServiceImplTest.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 42 more
    Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.urlshortener.model.Account] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
    List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.urlshortener.model.Account, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
    ]
```

Comment: So, two things:  when I attempt to hit your code at GitHub I get a 404; you should ***always*** post the relevant parts of your code here, and the constraint violation seems to be `name` is empty.  Are you sure that in your tests/uses of this bean that it isn't?

Comment: @Makoto, I have done some refactoring. Now I have updated the link. The problem is not in validation failure, but in the exception I get upon failure.

Answer (score 5):

This is the expected behavior, if you are interested in root cause check `TransactionSystemException#getRootCause` and perform any specific handling e.g.

```
@ExceptionHandler(TransactionSystemException.class)
public String handleConstrainException(TransactionSystemException ex) {
    if (ex.getRootCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        ConstraintViolationException constraintViolationException = (ConstraintViolationException) ex.getRootCause();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to fix, everything works as expected.

[`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/exception/ConstraintViolationException.html) is meant to be thrown when a database constraint is violated:

> Implementation of JDBCException indicating that the requested DML
>   operation resulted in a violation of a defined integrity constraint.

[Hibernate validator 5.x](http://hibernate.org/validator/) is an implementation of [Bean Validation 1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/), and as such is expected to behave according to the specification.

Comment: It throws javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException instead. Not org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yes, that's the expected behaviour.

Comment: So, if I am using REST then I should map TransactionSystemException and interpret it as validation failure? I looks ugly..

Comment: Do you know I it was different behavior in 1.0 version?

Comment: You can inspect the exception cause chain and check whether it contains `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException`. Regarding older versions, I am not sure, you can try it, but anyway the cause will be probably wrapped by Spring.